# Random variable and inequality

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

We consider a sequence of i.i.d random variables $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $E[X_0]=0$ and $E[X_0^2]<+\infty.$ Let $W_n=\sum_{k=0}^nX_k$ and for $r \in [0,1],$ let $Y_n(r)=W_{\left \lfloor{nr}\right \rfloor }+(nr-\left \lfloor{nr}\right \rfloor)X_{\left \lfloor{nr}\right \rfloor +1}.$

Prove that for $n \in \mathbb{N}^*,\sup_{r \in [0,1]}Y_n(r)=\max_{0 \leq k \leq n}W_k.$

If we let $0 \leq k \leq n$ then clearly $\sup_{r \in [0,1]}Y_n(r) \geq W_{k}.$

How can prove that if $r \in [0,1[,$ then $Y_n(r) \leq \max_{0 \leq k \leq n} W_k$ ?

If $r \in [0,1[$ then there exists $0 \leq k \leq n-1$ such that $r \in [k/n,(k+1)/n[$ so that $Y_n(r)=W_k+(nr-k)X_{k+1}.$ I can't see if this is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M_j=\sup_{r\in [j/n,(j+1)/n]}Y_n(r)$. Since $\sup_{r\in [0,1]}Y_n(r)=\max_{0\leqslant j\leqslant n-1}M_j$, it suffices to prove that
for each $j\in\{0,\dots,n-1\}$, $M_j\leqslant \max_{0\leqslant k\leqslant n}W_k$. To do so, observe that
$$
M_j=\max\left\{ W_j+(nr-j)X_{j+1},W_{j+1} \right\}.
$$
If $X_{j+1}$ is negative, then $r\in [j/n,(j+1)/n]\mapsto W_j+(nr-j)X_{j+1}$ is decreasing hence its maximal value on $[j/n,(j+1)/n]$ is reached at $j/n$.
By a similar reasoning, if $X_{j+1}$ is positive, the maximal value is reached at $(j+1)/n$. Therefore, $M_j\leqslant \max\left\{W_j,W_{j+1}\right\}$, giving the wanted conclusion.